# hashedmap and pointer to structs: CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

Tags: c, pointers, debugging, visual-studio-2012, hashmap

Im trying to create a simple hashmap in C. The vs doesnt know any errors at compilation time. But during execution, the pointer to the structure is becoming a bad pointer.

```
hashedKey CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
```

Here is the code for that, can anyone tell me why the code is crashing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


//#include"Header.h"
struct hashItem{
char* hashedKey;
char* hashedValue;
hashItem* next;
};
#define SIZE 20

unsigned long hashf(char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash%SIZE;
}

struct hashItem * createNewItem(char *key, char *value){
struct hashItem *newKeyValue = (struct hashItem *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct 
hashItem));
newKeyValue->hashedKey = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
newKeyValue->hashedValue = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
strcpy(newKeyValue->hashedKey, key);

newKeyValue->hashedValue = value;
newKeyValue->next = NULL;
return newKeyValue;
}

void put(struct hashItem** hashTable, char *key, char *value)
{
    if (value == NULL)
    return;

struct  hashItem *newKeyValue = createNewItem(key, value);

int index = hashf(key);

if (hashTable[index] == NULL){
    hashTable[index] = newKeyValue;
}
else
{
    int inserted = 0;
    struct hashItem *p = hashTable[index];
    struct hashItem *q = NULL;
    while (p != NULL){
        int e = strcmp(p->hashedKey, newKeyValue->hashedKey);
        if (e == 0){
            if (q != NULL)
                q->next = newKeyValue;
            p->hashedValue = newKeyValue->hashedValue;
            inserted = 1;
            break;
        }
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    if (!inserted)
        q->next = newKeyValue;
    }
}

struct hashItem * get(struct hashItem** hashTable, char *key){
    if (hashTable == NULL)
        return NULL;
    int index = hashf(key);
    if (hashTable[index] != NULL)
    {
    if (!strcmp(hashTable[index]->hashedKey, key)){
        return hashTable[index];
    }
    else{
        struct hashItem *p = hashTable[index];
        while (p != NULL){
            if (p->hashedKey == key)
                return p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    }
     else{
    return NULL;
}
}


int main(){


    hashItem** hashtable = (hashItem**)malloc(sizeof(hashItem*)*20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        hashtable[i] = (hashItem*)malloc(sizeof(hashItem));
        hashtable[i]->hashedKey = NULL;
        hashtable[i]->hashedValue = NULL;
        hashtable[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    put(hashtable, "select", "marks");

    hashItem* temp = (hashItem*)get(hashtable,"select");
    printf("%s", temp->hashedKey);
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    return 0;
}
```

During the debugging it seems the code is crashing at the exact line of:

```
struct hashItem *p = hashTable[index];
```

Please tell me why the code is crashing.

Comment: Step through your program in a debugger and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: either 'index' is outside of the hash table size, or you did no initialize hash table. Though there might be different reasons as well. run valgrind.

Comment: What is `using namespace std;` doing in a C program?!

Comment: what is `#include <iostream> doing in a C program?

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror()` to output the enclosed text AND the reason the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: there are a number of calls to `malloc()`,  each of those returned pointers needs to be passed to `free()` before exiting the program, to avoid any memory leaks

Comment: regarding:  `struct hashItem *q = NULL;
    while (p != NULL){
        int e = strcmp(p->hashedKey, newKeyValue->hashedKey);
        if (e == 0){
            if (q != NULL)` in function: `put()`  The value in `q` will always be NULL. on the first iteration of the loop,  it that what you want?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. indent after EVERY opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 20.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name,, then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: in the definition for `struct hashItem`, this line: `hashItem* next;` is not correct.  It needs to be: `struct hashItem* next;`

Comment: compiling the posted code results in MANY ERROR and WARNING messages being output by the compiler.  Are you expecting us to fix all your compile problems?  You state: *The vs doesnt know any errors at compilation time* that is flat out not correct.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: regarding: `int index = hashf(key);`  the function: `hashf()` returns a `long unsigned int` not a 'int`.

Comment: regarding:`int k; scanf("%d", &k);` this is an 'expensive' way to wait for a user input. And it can fall through if there is other than an integer or white space waiting in stdin

Comment: this statement: `hashItem** hashtable = malloc(sizeof( hashItem*)*20);` should be: `struct hashItem** hashtable = malloc(sizeof( hashtable )*20);` This line: `hashItem* temp = (hashItem*)get(hashtable,"select");` should be: `struct hashItem* temp = get(hashtable,"select");` as the function `get()` already returns a `struct hashItem*`

Comment: Thanks man @user3629249 these comments have been really helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are thinking wrong about initializing the hash buckets.

In the `main()` function basically you only need to allocate memory for the buckets of the hash table, so you only need this:

```
 hashItem** hashtable = (hashItem**)calloc(20, sizeof(hashItem**));
```

Pay attention that I am using `calloc` instead of `malloc` to make sure that it is going to initialize to `NULL` these memory region. So, basically here we created 20 buckets to be managed by the hash table.

Again, you should not do that `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)`, that is wrong. You will manage the buckets at insertion time, so, when you are inserting something that is not in the hash table, then you allocate memory to that entry.

You are using a mixture of `C` and `C++` here, please make sure to state that when you submit your question.

I will paste here the changes I made, because you were using a lot of casting to get the right pointer type, but it is not necessary if you usce the right structure types.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct _hashItem{
    char* hashedKey;
    char* hashedValue;
    struct _hashItem* next;
} hashItem;
#define SIZE 20

unsigned long hashf(char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return (hash % SIZE);
}

hashItem * createNewItem(char *key, char *value){
    hashItem *newKeyValue = (hashItem *)calloc(1, sizeof(
                hashItem));
    newKeyValue->hashedKey = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    newKeyValue->hashedValue = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    strcpy(newKeyValue->hashedKey, key);

    newKeyValue->hashedValue = value;
    newKeyValue->next = NULL;
    return newKeyValue;
}

void put(hashItem** hashTable, char *key, char *value)
{
    if (value == NULL)
        return;

    hashItem *newKeyValue = createNewItem(key, value);

    int index = hashf(key);

    if (hashTable[index] == NULL){
        hashTable[index] = newKeyValue;
    }
    else
    {
        int inserted = 0;
        hashItem *p = hashTable[index];
        hashItem *q = NULL;
        while (p != NULL){
            int e = strcmp(p->hashedKey, newKeyValue->hashedKey);
            if (e == 0){
                if (q != NULL)
                    q->next = newKeyValue;
                p->hashedValue = newKeyValue->hashedValue;
                inserted = 1;
                break;
            }
            q = p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        if (!inserted)
            q->next = newKeyValue;
    }
}

hashItem * get(hashItem** hashTable, char *kAey){
    if (hashTable == NULL)
        return NULL;
    int index = hashf(key);
    if (hashTable[index] != NULL)
    {
        if (!strcmp(hashTable[index]->hashedKey, key)){
            return hashTable[index];
        }
        else{
            hashItem *p = hashTable[index];
            while (p != NULL){
                if (p->hashedKey == key)
                    return p;
                p = p->next;
            }
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
}


int main(){
    hashItem** hashtable = (hashItem**)calloc(20, sizeof(hashItem**));

    put(hashtable, "select", "marks");

    hashItem* temp = get(hashtable,"select");
    printf("%s", temp->hashedKey);
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. that was a very detailed explanation. Understood my mistake

Comment: the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression in the calls to `malloc()`

Comment: see my comment, to the OPs question about calling the heap allocation functions.